# Windows Store - Crash/Memory/Hangs analyse

Tags: memory, crash, windows-store-apps, freeze, windows-10-universal

In this moment, I have many Crash/Hangs/Memory events from Windows Store. In my app, I use Google Analytics but, recently, I implement Microsoft Applications Insights for get more information about this events, but, the problem are the same, I have small information, to detect where is the problem inside application.

I download report file, from store, but the file are in .TSV format.
I try use WinDBG for analyse this event, but this, not accept .TSF file but by example accept .CAB format.
In store, report always generated in .TSV format.

**Example Crash (From Windows Store):**

```
- APPLICATION_FAULT_11ee0_MyApp.dll!Unknown
- INVALID_POINTER_READ_c0000005_igd10iumd64.dll!OpenAdapter10_2
- INVALID_POINTER_READ_c0000005_msmpeg2vdec.dll!TaskScheduler_FindAndExecuteTask
- NULL_POINTER_READ_c0000005_mfsvr.dll!CSimpleVRStreamSink::PresentFrame
- MEMORY_CORRUPTION_STRIDE_AFTER_CALL_c0000005_memory_corruption!Windows_UI_Xaml
```

---

**Example Hang (From Windows Store):**

```
- APPLICATION_HANG_QUIESCE_THROTTLED_PRELAUNCH_cfffffff_E3d14332.MyAppName!outstanding_deferrals
- APPLICATION_HANG_QUIESCE_THROTTLED_PRELAUNCH_BlockedOn_FileIO_cfffffff_E3d14332.MyAppName!outstanding_deferrals
- APPLICATION_HANG_ACTIVATION_RESUME_PRELAUNCH_BusyHang_cfffffff_E3d14332.MyAppName!activation_in_progress
- MISSING_DUMP_80000003_E3d14332.MyAppName_1.3.5.0_x64__x5pj8nbyjfjhfgdr72!Unknown
- APPLICATION_HANG_QUIESCE_THROTTLED_PRELAUNCH_BusyHang_cfffffff_E3d14332.MyAppName!outstanding_deferrals
- APPLICATION_HANG_QUIESCE_THROTTLED_PRELAUNCH_BlockedOn_AlpcPort_cfffffff_E3d14332.MyAppName!outstanding_deferrals
- APPLICATION_HANG_ACTIVATION_BusyHang_dfffffff_E3d14332.MyAppName!unknown_error_in_application
- APPLICATION_HANG_ACTIVATION_BusyHang_cfffffff_E3d14332.MyAppName!unknown_error_in_application
```

---

**Example Memory (From Windows Store):**

```
- INVALID_ARG_FAILURE_c0000409_Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.dll!DllCanUnloadNow
- MISSING_DUMP_80000003_E3d14332.MyAppName_1.3.5.0_x64__x5pj8nbyjfjhfgdr72!Unknown
- SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_NULL_c0000005_aticfx64.dll!Unknown
- FAST_FAIL_UNEXPECTED_HEAP_EXCEPTION_c0000409_E3d14332.MyAppName!unknown_error_in_application
- STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN_c0000409_msxml6.dll!URLMONRequest::_CallOnHeadersAvailable
- FATAL_APP_EXIT_c0000409_Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CD3D11DeviceInstance::RecordDeviceAsLost
```

---

**WinDBG + .CAB analyse:**  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephe/archive/2015/03/30/how-to-make-use-of-crash-dumps-available-on-the-store-dev-portal.aspx

---

Someone, help me in this problem? Any tool read and analyse .TSF file from generated by Windows Store? Any information about this events?

Thanks